# setinterval() and .click() in a Greasemonkey script

Tags: javascript, click, greasemonkey, setinterval

I've tried to develop a simple Greasemonkey script in javascript. How can I automatically simulate a click on specific button with an interval between each click?

Here's my code:

```
var Next=document.getElementsByClassName("SubmitButton");

for (var i=0, c = Next.length; i<c; i++)
{
    Next[i].click();
    setTimeout('Next[i].click()',3000);
}
```

The problem is that the code only clicks on the first value of `Next`. Why?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are setting the timeout for all actions to the same time, so they will all run at the same time.

Also, you are using the variable `i` in the code, which will run after the loop has completed, so it will point to the index after the last item in the array.

Use a closure to make a separate variable for each item, and use an anonymous function instead of a string for the code to execute in the timeout:

```
var Next = document.getElementsByClassName("SubmitButton");

for (var i = 0, c = Next.length; i < c; i++) {

//Next[i].click();

  (function(element, time){

    setTimeout(function(){ element.click(); }, time);

  })(Next[i], 3000 * i);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problems are:

1. [Auto-eval Strings will not work properly in Greasemonkey](http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Greasemonkey_Hacks/Getting_Started#Pitfall_.231%3a_Auto-eval_Strings) (and they should be avoided in any case). So pass a function to `setTimeout()`.  This will work; **note how the parameter is handled**:

   ```
   var Next = document.getElementsByClassName ("SubmitButton");

   for (var i=0, c = Next.length; i<c; i++) {
       Next[i].click();
       setTimeout (function (J) {Next[J].click(); }, 3000, i);
   }
   ```
2. You seem to want an interval, and have marked this question with `setinterval` twice.  But the code uses `setTimeout`, which only fires once instead of every 3 seconds.  Perhaps you want to use `setinterval`?

   ```
       setinterval (function (J) {Next[J].click(); }, 3000, i);
   ```
3. This seems to be clicking submit button(s).  Is it loading a new page. or triggering AJAX?  If so, this scheme may only fire once or twice.
   Link to the target page and describe its behavior better.